# In IntelliJ, How Do I Fix "These Files Do Not Belong to the Project"?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently put several old, yucky git directory structures into one new, clean structure in SVN, then pulled the entire SVN repository back out into a new, clean, local git repository. One IntelliJ project was so messed up I had to import the old IntelliJ project, which created a new `.iml` file having a better name, and deleted the old `.iml` file. I reconfigured everything, committed back into SVN, and verified other people could open the project and build.

Today I tried to edit a file for the first time in this project and got the message, "These files do not belong to the project". IntelliJ offers to unlock the file or all non-project files in the current session, but both options sound wrong. What have I done to myself, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Switching SVN and git that often sounds confusing. How about you checkout the whole project from the VCS again if you did not change any file yet?

Comment: It was a one-time event. I did check the entire project out again. What convinces IDEA that files belong to a project?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm using git-svn.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The file was still open from before all the shuffling, and was apparently pointing at the original file in its original location! I closed the editor and reopened the file from the project tree without a problem. I hope this helps someone else someday.

Comment: After some time, but maybe it will indeed help someone. It happens because the project is part of a bigger project. File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart did the trick for me, simply restarting the app did not.

Comment: It's probably listed in one of the XML config files in `.idea/workspace.xml`. Just do a find of that folder for the name of the file in question, and remove the entry for it from the XML. Mine was listed within the following node: `<component name="TypeScriptGeneratedFilesManager">`. Then invalidated caches and restart, file is treated as a standard file again. This way you can keep all your settings without exporting them and importing them again.

Answer (score 111):

This happened for me when I ignored the .idea/ files. Just do

```
rm -rf .idea/
```

And then File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate And Restart.

Comment: This worked but it does wipe out any IDE changes you have made for the project so be careful.  You may want to look at what others suggest.

Answer (score 56):

From File-> Repair IDE -> Rescan Project Indexes -> Reopen Project worked for me.

Comment: This solved my problem : when opening the project, all the main "app" folders where not located under "Project" but under "Project Files" and considered as "Non project Files". As a result, I could not edit them directly and I could not search through the project to find a file by name or a piece of code.

Comment: repair-ide-tool from flamingo recommended me this step and it hepled

Comment: worked for me on 2023.1

Comment: Did not work for me :/ I am on Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 20):

Had same problem on Ubuntu (Webstorm), got answer from Intellij.

> There are no content roots in your project, so all your files are
> treated as non-project files. As I wrote your .idea files are likely
> broken, the .iml file and/or modules.xml are either missing or
> corrupted. Deleting and re-creating .idea folder should help:
>
> -close the project
>
> -remove it from Recent projects list
>
> -shut down the IDE
>
> -delete the .idea folder
>
> -restart, open the project root folder with File > Open

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/3779670?page=1

Comment: Worked for my issue with WebStorm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

This also happened for me when I opened the project through a symlink (parent directory) or when the python interpreter was inside a symlink directory (because of virtualenv).

Reopening through the original directory tree (after fighting hard with the IDE to forget its beloved project settings), solved the issue.

Comment: Inspired by this answer, I just deleted the `.idea` directory, open the project again, and boom, could edit.

Comment: I had the same problem when I open a Scala project from a symlink, and I solved this issue by accessing the original directory as recommended.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably listed in one of the XML config files in `.idea/*.xml`.

Just do a find of that folder for the name of the file in question, and remove the entry for it from the XML.

Mine was listed in `.idea/workspace.xml` within the following node: `<component name="TypeScriptGeneratedFilesManager">`.

I removed the option, then invalidated caches and restarted, and now the file is marked as a standard, non-generated file again. This way you can keep all your settings without exporting them and importing them.

Answer (score 3):

For me the above did not help. I ended up going `Project Structure -> Modules ->` + at the top narrow middle `column -> browsed` through files to select the **Project** `Folder -> apply -> ok -> all` is done and working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue with WebStorm. The difference was I had to shutdown the IDE completely and then remove .idea folder
`rm -rf .idea`
I tried doing it with the IDE open and going to file `File -> Invalidate Caches` but that did not fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. File was considered not part of the project even if I deleted it and created a new one with the same name.

To fix,I highlighted the project node in the left panel, selected "File/Invalidate caches and restart" from the top menu.

After the restart I had to set my file as a JS file (right click, set as JavaScript), close and reopen the project. All fixed.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm > Preferences > Project > Project Structure > Add Content Root

Somehow PyCharm lost the project root directory in my case

Comment: Please consider adding some screenshots on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Check: **Settings > Project > Project Structure** and verify that your files/folder are not excluded. If they are, right click and uncheck Excluded, or click on the "x" (highlighted in red circle)

(sorry, I can't post an inline image yet)
[Image of Settings Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBftI.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was much simpler than expected: I was trying to run a Jupyter notebook and got the error - because it was inside a folder that was marked "excluded" in the project structure.

Simply moving the notebook out of the excluded folder solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was auto-generated `.gitignore`, I had entries like:

```
### npm ###
node
node_modules
frontend-dest
data/
```

And in project files I had java package called like `com.company.test.data` which matched last pattern. I strongly recommend to check it before removing `.idea/` files and invalidating cache.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is an IDE issue that Android Studio cannot recognise the current directory **if it does not include any source files**.
So, **adding am empty source file, e.g `empty_xxx.c` under the directory** in question and adding below line in `CMakeList.txt`

```
add_library(${TARGET_NAME_XXX} SHARED ${SOME_DIR_HAVING_THIS_WARNING}/empty_xxx.c)
```

will help get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the above methods didn't help, I just deleted .idea file in project and reset the Jetbrain IDE to default settings and it worked normally.

NB: You will loose all your settings and plugins, but if you don't mind this might help as the last resort like in my case.
I am using Jetbrain,

Answer (score 0):

make sure to include all project files in the project. Use Settings -> project structure.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I had moved a project to wsl by copying the files from wsl to windows. When I switched branches the file must've been open from before and was the windows version of it and not the wsl one.

I noticed this finally by looking on top of the file tab and seeing the path as `C:\User...\filename` instead of `\\wsl$....\filename`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

1. Close your Intellij idea of the particular project.
2. Goto your project folder in the file explorer and look for .idea folder.
3. Delete it. Reopen the project in IntelliJ.
4. Now your project files are loaded and could be edited.

Comment: The top-rated answer from over four years ago already covers this. Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score -3):

Close your JetBrains IDE, then open a Terminal window and navigate to your project's root folder, and run these 2 commands:

```
rm -rf .idea
```

and then

```
rm -rf .git
```

NOTE: you'll probably have to connect your project back to your git repository, so if you have any uncommitted changes make sure to commit and push them beforehand to avoid losing them.

Comment: I would not delete .git as this would permanently remove all the local git commits that are not pushed yet

Comment: Hell fucking no, deleting `.git` forces you to reconnect to the remote in unsafe ways that can lose you files. There are a million ways to deal with this, deleting `.git` is not one of them.