# Pycharm Python can't run existing jupyter notebook, only if I create it myself

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

I can't open existing Jupyter Notebooks.

I downloaded some Jupyter Notebooks but when opening them and trying to run a cell I get this error:

> 'This file does not belong to the project'.

The only solution I found was to copy all it's content create a new Jupyter Notebook in the project and paste it in there, then when I try to run a cell it al works fine, but that gets very time consuming.

I am using PyCharm, and python 3.8.7, and Jupyter 1.0.0

How can I open a Jupyter Notebook file without creating one and copying it in there?

I came across this question but that didn't help me

[In IntelliJ, How Do I Fix "These Files Do Not Belong to the Project"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099716/in-intellij-how-do-i-fix-these-files-do-not-belong-to-the-project)